# Batch APEX requiring two queries and hitting limits

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits

I have a batch APEX class that is used to delete any contacts that have been created over a year ago and have no related opportunities. 
I have queries for the contacts in the QueryLocator. I am then querying for all opportunities in the execute however am hitting limits. 
Can anyone suggest how I can query all opportunities without errors?

Batch Class

```
global class DeleteContact implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

global date d = system.today().addYears(-1).addDays(-3);
public String query = 'select id, opportunity__c, RecordTypeId, email, customer_Number__c from contact where createddate <= :d';

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope){
    Map<Id, Id> oppMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
    Map<Id, Contact> contactMap = new Map<Id, Contact>();
    List<Contact> contactsInScope = new List<Contact>();

    for(Contact c: scope){
        if(!contactMap.containsKey(c.id)){
            contactMap.put(c.id, c);
        }
    }



    List<Opportunity> opportunities = new List<Opportunity>();

    opportunities = [select id, contact__c, stagename from opportunity where contact__c != ''];

    for(Opportunity o : opportunities){
        if(contactMap.containskey(o.Contact__c) ){
            oppMap.put(o.Contact__c, o.id);
        }
    }

    for(Contact con : scope){
        if(!oppMap.containsKey(con.id)){
            contactsInScope.add(con);
        }
    }

    Id b2cId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('B2C Contact').getRecordTypeId();

    List<Contact> contactsToDelete = new List<Contact>();

    for(Contact co : contactsInScope){
            if(co.RecordTypeId == b2cId){
                if(co.Customer_Number__c == ''){
                    if(!co.email.contains('@***emaildomain.co.uk')){
                        contactsToDelete.add(co);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    if(contactsToDelete.size()>0){
        try{
            delete contactsToDelete;
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }

}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

}
```

}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have few recommendation regarding your code:

- Make query [selective](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=How-to-make-my-SOQL-query-selective&language=en_US&r=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com.ua%2F&type=1). `[select id, contact__c, stagename from opportunity where contact__c != ''];` is a bad query
- Split large methods into few small methods. Method `execute` is too large
- Pass as `queryLocator` not just `String` of query, but static `SOQL` query. It could prevent from having runtime exceptions to compile exceptions, that are more easy to fix. instead of `Database.getQueryLocator('select id from Account');` use `Database.getQueryLocator([select id from Account]);`
- Catch exceptions only if you know what to do with it, otherwise you will not receive any errors if those occur

---

```
try{
    delete contactsToDelete;
}
catch(Exception e){} // is not a best practice
```

---

your code could be re-write to query Contacts, that are not in Contact__c on Opportunities

```
global class DeleteContact implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    private Date dateToDeleteTo;

    global DeleteContact(){
        dateToDeleteTo = Date.today().addYears(-1).addDays(-3);
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        Id b2cId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('B2C Contact').getRecordTypeId();
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            select Id
            from Contact
            where Id not in (
                select Contact__c
                from Opportunity
                where Contact__c != null
                )
            and RecordTypeId = :b2cId
            and Email like '%@icslearn.co.uk'
            and CreatedDate <= :dateToDeleteTo
            ]);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope){
        delete scope;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

Comment: I would bet that the OP would also prefer the behavior of `Database.delete(scope, false)` to still delete rows that don't fail the deletion even if one does.  If he wanted to add better error logging this would also help facilitate that.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily optimize this code. First query Opportunity as child records instead of querying all opportunity in system. Which will also reduce your line of code.

```
global class DeleteContact implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

global date d = system.today().addYears(-1).addDays(-3);
//check and verify relationship name
public String query = 'select id, opportunity__c, RecordTypeId, email, customer_Number__c, (SELECT ID FROM Opportunity__r LIMIT 1) from contact where createddate <= :d';

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope){


    Id b2cId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('B2C Contact').getRecordTypeId();

    List<Contact> contactsToDelete = new List<Contact>();
    // just check the child list size . if its 0 then it don't have record and you can proceed to delete
    for(Contact co : contactsInScope){
            if(co.Opportunity__r.size() == 0 && co.RecordTypeId == b2cId && co.Customer_Number__c == '' && !co.email.contains('@icslearn.co.uk')){
                contactsToDelete.add(co);
            }
    }
     //As this is Asyn so try catch won't make a difference here and you can remove them
    delete contactsToDelete;

    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
}
```